# Como criar aplicação desktop cliente para acesso a banco de dados sem expor informações de segurança?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, servidor

Já havia feito aplicação web com acesso a banco de dados MySQL via PHP e sei que os arquivos de configuração para acesso ao banco de dados ficam no lado servidor, sendo retornado apenas os dados necessários ao navegador do usuário, ou seja, o usuário não tem acesso a tais dados.

Se eu fazer uma aplicação desktop cliente para acesso a banco de dados remotamente é possível que alguém faça engenharia reversa para pegar a senha do banco através da "connectionString"? Se sim, como devo proceder?

Comment: creio eu que não é possível, a não ser que fique brechar de paineis de adm, ou de consultas que n deveriam ter ( mas como disse: 'creio' nao é certeza )

Comment: Obrigado. Pesquisei no google sobre o tema, mas não encontrei nada muito claro. Valeu ;)

Comment: Em princípio, basta não colocar a senha no software, e dar permissões corretas para os usuários corretos. Assim, eles digitarão a senha ao logar no sistema, e se acessarem diretamente o DB só vão poder fazer o que o soft já permitiria normalmente. Uma solução intermediária (mais para espantar "curioso") é você fazer um hash da senha do usuário e mesclar com a do DB, assim a senha original do DB dependerá do usuário digitar a senha correta. Em ambos os casos, nunca armazene a senha _hardcoded_ no software.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Bacco

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não conecte a aplicação cliente diretamente ao serviço do banco de dados, pois se no código da sua aplicação houver nomes de usuários e senhas, seu banco de dados ficará em risco.

Darei algumas sugestões para que, de acordo com a arquitetura do seu sistema, possa avaliar se é o que pode resolver a sua situação.

1- As consultas e envios (requests e responses) podem ser feitos via webservice, trocando dados em formato JSON ou XML, por exemplo.
Ao autenticar o usuário, sugiro atribuir um token ao mesmo, que pode ser enviado a cada consulta enquanto a sessão estiver ativa, servindo como uma chave de acesso.
Sugestões para criar seus webservices Yii2 (PHP) e Django (python)

2- Firebase pode ser uma solução interessante, pois ele dispõe de um banco de dados em tempo real, onde é possível configurar as permissões de escrita e leitura pelos nós. Spoiler: A documentação é bem vasta e há muitos recursos para autenticação.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que queria saber, George Tavares! Obrigado!